# How to set relative url for a css file in Django

Tags: python, css, django

[image]

My django project is pictured above:

I'm trying to set a path to my css using:

```
<link href="{% static "css/bootstrap.min.css" %} rel="stylesheet">
```

In my settings.py I have:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  'templates'),
```

When I run the project I get:

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /index/

Invalid block tag: 'static'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have {% load staticfiles %}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem maybe is: You don't loaded tag for staticfiles.

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

You should load staticfiles first, and then you can use static tag.

Comment: Make sure you put this at least above the first time you use `{% static %}`. Also note that you will need to use `{% load staticfiles %}` in each template that you want to use the `{% static %}` tag.